# how to apply background color dynamically to dropdown in angular 8 when using *ngFor

Tags: angular

**HTML code**

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: flex !important;"
    *ngFor="let mesureitem of sampledetails.ActualMeasurements;let i = index">
    <div class="col pl-0">
        <label>Actual Status({{mesureitem.Name}}) </label>
        <select class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event)" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':selectedColor}"
            [(ngModel)]="mesureitem.ActualStatus">
            <option [ngValue]="selected" selected disabled>Select Status</option>
            <option *ngFor="let color of colors" [ngValue]="color.colorvalue" class="textColor"
                [ngStyle]="{'background-color':color.colorvalue}">{{color.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS code**

```
colors = [
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Replace',
        colorvalue: '#E60000'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Good',
        colorvalue: '#33CC33'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Monitor',
        colorvalue: '#FFA500'
    }
];

onChange(value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.colors.length; i++) {
        if (this.colors[i].id == value.target.selectedOptions[0].index) {
            this.selectedColor = value.target.selectedOptions[0].style.backgroundColor;
        }
    }
}
```

>
*1. i have two dropdowns which are getting dynmically from API and WHEN I SELECT one dropdown automatically second dropdown background color also getting effected*
>

Comment: add your code in https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Please find the stackblitz link :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-om8zo4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are binding the selected values to same variable.

Change `ngStyle` like this,

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':mesureitem.ActualStatus}"
```

You can remove the `onChange()` function and `selectedColor` variable which are unnecessary.

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhyuzw

Comment: still i have doubt  if i want to use ID for that how to use

Comment: please tell me how to get ID with ngmodel bec i have to submit ID to database

Comment: @Chaitanya What id? The value of selected status?

Comment: If you want the id of selected colour, bind the entire colour object instead of just the colour value. Thus your `ActualStatus` field becomes an object. You can obtain the selected colour value from it for using in `ngStyle`.  Check this : [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqmrts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqmrts)

Comment: iam doing two way binding ,if you dont mind can you share updated one  in stackblitz.com